# How to handle exception raised at low levels of the package or function calls?

Tags: python, exception

For example, my function call make look like the following:

```
def parse(self, text):

   ...

   return self.parse_helper(text)

@staticmethod
def parser_helper(text):
    ...
    return normalize(text)

@staticmethod
def normalize(text):
   ...
   try:
      ...
   except:
     raise ValueError('normalize failed.')
```

If the 'parse' is the function to be provided to users to call, if an exception occurs in normalize(), the whole program terminates. To avoid this, to let users decide what to do when exception occurs, do I have to and try ... except blocks into both 'parser_helper' and 'parse', and let use to use try...except when 'parse' is called?

What's the normal practice of handling this? If there are a few more layers of function calls embedded other than 3 as shown below, do I have to use try ... except block in each layer of function, in order to transfer the handling of exception to the end users at the very top?

Comment: Yes, you generally catch and propagate exceptions up to whatever level is supposed to handle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practice to pass a parameter to decide wether to raise or be silent regarding an exception, is something that exists, for example in [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

You could do

```
def parse(self, text, error_silent=False):

     ...
    try:
        return self.parse_helper(text)
    except ValueError as e:
        if error_silent:
            return None
        raise e
```

Comment: In order to do this, you need to add try ... except to parser_helper() too. Right? So if the raising errors originates from the very low level, you need try ... except blocks all the way up to the final public interface, i.e. 'parse'.  Right?

Comment: @marlon Nope, the error will propagate to the parent function until  : either there is an except OR thr program crashes